# C++: call a top class method from the attribute class

Tags: c++

I would like to call a method of the parent class from the child class.

The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdio.h"

class Parent;

typedef void (Parent::*fff)(void);

// Attribute class
class Child {
public:
    Child( fff ftp );
    void (Parent::*fptr)(void);
    void update();
};

Child::Child( fff ftp )
{
    fptr = ftp;
}

void Child::update()
{
    (this->*fptr)(); // fail and I don't know the correct syntax 
    printf("update done\n");    
}

// Top class
class Parent {
public:
    Parent();
    Child child;
    void foo();

};


Parent::Parent():
        child( &Parent::foo )
{
    (this->*child.fptr)(); // works and print "foo"
}

void Parent::foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

int main()
{
    Parent parent;
    parent.child.update();
}
```

This code fails. I get the following error: "error: pointer to member type 'void (Parent::)()' incompatible with object type 'Child'"

It is maybe obvious but I don't find the correct syntax. Any idea ?

Comment: Syntax is correct but you need to call it on `Parent ` instance instead of `Child` instance

Comment: Don't agree neither on downvote nor on closing the question. It is an [mcve], and the problem is clearly described. User not understanding the *true* nature of the problem does not disqualify the question itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working case (dropping irrelevant details):

```
Parent::Parent()
// ^ (!)
{
    (this->*child.fptr)();
}
```

`this` is of type `Parent`, so you can use it to call a `Parent` function on.

Non-working case:

```
void Child::update()
//     ^ (!)
{
    (this->*fptr)(); 
}
```

`this` is of type `Child`, but the member function pointer refers to class `Parent`, so you have mismatching argument types (but it is not a matter of syntax, which is correct). The situation is comparable to the following one:

```
class C
{
public:
    static void f(C* c);
};

class D
{
public:
     void f()
     {
         C::f(this); // fails, 'this' is not C*, but D*!
     }
}
```

Matter changes, if you let `Child` inherit from `Parent`. If this is appropriate depends on the use case, but as `Child` already is an aggregated member of `Parent`, it isn't even possible in *given* scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very clear.
According that, it is not possible to do what I want. I understand why now.